# Celery task will not execute

Tags: python, django, celery

I've followed the [instruction process to installing and setting up celery](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/20/how-to-use-celery-with-django.html), now I'm trying to execute my task. My project tree looks like this:

```
bin
draft1--
        |
         -------draft1 ----
                           |
                            --------celery.py
                            --------tasks.py
                            --------views.py
         -------manage.py
         -------templates

include
lib
```

Here's my code:

settings.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'
```

celery.py

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')

app = Celery('app')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

tasks.py

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def print_this():
    print('ONE MINUTE')
```

app.views

```
print_this.delay()
```

So my celery function doesn't work, it doesn't execute the print statement. What I want to do is execute the function every minute. Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to read more before just starting to experiment. Celery is a distributed task queue, which basically means, it polls a queue to see if there is any task that needs to be run. If there is, it runs the task.

About your setup, you seem to have a task runner, but not the queue that runner requires to poll to check if there is any tasks to be run. The configuration `CELERY_BROKER_URL` is about that queue. I suggest you start by reading ["Celery's Introduction documents"](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/introduction.html). Especially ["What do I need?"](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/introduction.html#what-do-i-need) part.

**NOTE FOR AFTER YOU FIGURE OUT THE QUEUE PART**

Also, I am not sure how do you run and serve your django application, but celery requires separate processes. For that part you will need to skim ["First Steps with Celery"](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html).

Comment: I've read everything and I'm not sure there's anything to "figure out" about the queue part? I'm running my app in django's local server so the `CELERY_BROKER_URL` should be the same for me as in the instructions. I tried`./bin/celery -A draft1 worker -l info` in my project root (where manage.py is) and it returned this error: `AttributeError: module 'draft1' has no attribute 'app'` / `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:` `AttributeError: module 'draft1' has no attribute 'celery'` Any idea what this could mean? (`draft1 is my app name`)

Comment: Did you setup a queue server? Like rabbitmq?

Comment: Yes, both my django server and rabbitmq are running.

Comment: Then add a user to rabbitmq. And point your django + celery application to your rabbitmq broker with `CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://user:password@host:port'` (assuming you are running rabbitmq server on localhost)

Comment: I've changed my `CELERY_BROKER_URL` to the correct value, and I'm logged in to my RabbotMQ in my browser. Can you tell me how I can execute my function? I believe I have all the tools in place however my function does not work. All my code is in my post.

Comment: I assume your project is trivial, can you please try following official tutorial step by step? I think you might have skipped something. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django

Comment: I am also having this problem? Was there a solution?